# Flutter Firestore documentsnapshot to Map

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

For my flutter app, I am fetching a collection as a querysnapshot and converting it into a list using:

```
var dataList = snapShot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
```

Works like a charm, no issues till now.

Lately, I've been trying to manipulate the data in the collection and for that, I need the docId. But for some reason, the list does not have the docId included.

There should be a quick way of including the doc id while converting a snapshot to a list.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add `e.id` to your map.

```
var dataList = snapShot.docs.map((e) {
          Map value = e.data();
          value['docId'] = e.id;
          return value;
        }).toList();
```

Or You can create model class and add `docId` to model class below way.

you can return List of Object using this way

```dart
        return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) => 
    Model.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
```

your model class

```dart
    class Model {
      final String categoryId;
    
      Model({this.categoryId});
    
      factory Model.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        Map data = doc.data();
    
        return Model(
          docId: doc.id,
          categoryId: data['categoryId'],
        // other fields
        );
     }
    }
```

Comment: Great! I used the first solution as it suited best and it worked.

Comment: This returns the DocID's as strings?  What if we want a list of DocumentReference?

Comment: use this way, `  return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) => doc).toList());`